# AIC formula in latex

Tags: symbols, math-operators

Excuse my naive question, have been searching around a lot!

How could I properly write the formula for the AIC estimation in a Latex Article?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: `$\mathrm{AIC}=2k-2\ln\bigl(\hat{L}\bigr)$` should do it, albeit with `\widehat`, it  would probably look better.

Comment: Thank you Bernard!!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you obtained the screenshot of the formula you're interested in replicating from the [AIC Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). If you click on that page's "edit" button, you'll find the following math-ml expression that underlies the screenshot you posted:

```
<math>\mathrm{AIC} \, = \, 2k - 2\ln(\hat L)</math>
```

Translating this code to "pure" LaTeX, you might write

```
\begin{math} \mathrm{AIC} = 2k - 2\ln(\hat L) \end{math}
```

or, more succinctly,

```
$\mathrm{AIC} = 2k - 2\ln(\hat L)$
```

where `$` is a TeX-special character that's used to initiate and terminate inline math mode.

As @Bernard has noted in a comment, using `\widehat` instead of `\hat` would make the formula look even better, especially if one dispenses with the unnecessary parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{AIC} = 2k - 2\ln\widehat{L}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `\widehat` is better.

Answer (score 2):

You should write something like:

```
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{AIC}
     = 2 k - 2 \ln \widehat{L}
\end{equation}
```

The `\mathrm{...}` bit gives roman (upright, spaced as text, not a sequence of three variables).

Comment: AIC is an acronym for "Akaike Information Criterion" and is named for the Japanese statistician Hirotsugu Akaike, who first proposed it as a model selection criterion roughly 50 years ago. The AIC is is computed as the sum of (i) the (negative of) the model likelihood (`\widehat{L}`) and (ii) a linear penalty term (`2k`), the number of parameters used in the estimating the model. The AIC is *not* an operator in the normal sense of the word. The upshot? Just write `\mathrm{AIC}`.

Comment: @Mico, learned some (La)TeX today. Thanks!